# proxy haproxy or web server not rendering the content

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I trying to setup a basic infra-structure using `haproxy` as a proxy server.

Here is my basic environment

**Domain Name:** example.com

**Proxy Server**

- OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- Software: haproxy server
- IP: 100.100.100.101

*proxy config file:* have added/configured this two sections

```
frontend http-frontend
        bind 100.100.100.101:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
        default_backend webserver

backend webserver
        server 1-www 100.100.100.102:80 check
        #server 2-www private_ip_2:80 check # use for load balance
```

**Web Server**

- OS: Debian Jessie 8.7
- Software: Nginx/PHP-FPM/MySQL
- IP: 100.100.100.102

**DNS** is pointing to my proxy IP: 100.100.100.101

```
Type A 100.100.100.101
CNAME example.com
```

**Obs.:**
The redirection is occurring without a problem when the domain name is called in a browser, but the content from the web server is not downloaded (I got an Unable to connect error).
I had installed Let's Encrypt in my web server IP: 100.100.100.102, perhaps it is causing the problem?
Also in my nginx config file I created a rule to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS just in case users forget to use https://.

My doubt here is, should I have installed Let's Encrypt in my proxy or web server(actually installed)?

Thanks.

**[EDITED]**
After all, this is how my haproxy config file looks like, for those interested, it is working in my environment.

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
        maxconn 2048
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  forwardfor
        option  http-server-close
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend www-http
        bind 100.100.100.101:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
        default_backend wwwbackend

frontend www-https
        bind 100.100.100.101:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/mydomain.tld.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
        use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl
        default_backend wwwbackend

backend wwwbackend
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
        server mamba 100.100.100.102:80 check
        server taipan 100.100.100.103:80 check
        server viper 100.100.100.104:80 check
        server cobra 100.100.100.105:80 check

backend letsencrypt-backend
        server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:22222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting your users to HTTPS and your `haproxy` config is missing configuration for HTTPS. You need to configure your `haproxy` to listen on port 443 and pass requests to you `nginx` backend. You'll need to install your Let's Encrypt certificate on the `haproxy` too.

Comment: Then I have to install the certificate Let's Encrypt in both web server and `haproxy`?

Comment: You can pass requests from `haproxy` to your backend either through HTTP or HTTPS. In the second case you'll need security certificate on the `nginx` too. In the first case you'll need to configure `nginx` not to redirect to HTTPS if user's connection to `haproxy` was over HTTPS.

Comment: Let's Encrypt certificate was created for my domain name, the DNS was pointing to the web server, but now the DNS is pointing my domain name to the `haproxy`. As I said the request is passing to web server, but not connecting. Should I revoke the certificate in the web server and create a new one? I have only one domain name, the web server will have only the IP address now.

Comment: the request from `haproxy` is passing to the web server via http only, to use https I think I need to install a new certificate to the webserver, right?

Comment: just check, let's encrypt does not allow certificates for public/private IP addresses.

Comment: You can just copy existing Let's Encrypt certificate to the `haproxy`. You don't need a new certificate on the `nginx` as long as it is configured to handle the same domain name.

Comment: I'll try that in a minute.

Comment: I did obtain a new cert using a built-in “standalone” webserver for my domain from Let's Encrypt. Now it is working properly. When you said "just copy" I knew it was going to work, but instead I did a new installation.
AlexD, thank you very much for the help, I will accept your answer as correct, you point me in the right direction when you said my `haproxy` config file was missing the HTTPS configuration, then I added this new section ->
`frontend wwwhttps     bind 100.100.100.101:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/mydomain.tld.pem` after the certificate was installed.